# How to add favicon to ActiveAdmin in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I add a favicon in Active Admin. I am using rails 3.2 and active admin 0.4.3

Answer (score 20):

Though this question is about an older version of ActiveAdmin, as of [this commit](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/17afb732ef98c0631a5949e32b8c31f0dff5766e) ActiveAdmin supports favicons in the initializer. Around line 145 of active_admin.rb for me:

```
  # == Setting a Favicon
  #
  # config.favicon = '/assets/favicon.ico'
```

HTH the next person who comes along. I almost did the top-voted answer...

Answer (score 2):

Until they support favicon you can do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('head').append("<link href='favicon.ico' rel='shortcut icon'>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add it to your ActiveAdmin.rb initializer like so :

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Views
    module Pages
      class Base < Arbre::HTML::Document

        def build_active_admin_head
          within @head do
            insert_tag Arbre::HTML::Title, [title, render_or_call_method_or_proc_on(self, active_admin_application.site_title)].join(" | ")
            insert_tag Arbre::HTML::Link, rel: 'shortcut icon', href: '/favicon.gif'
            #                          Change the href used in this line ^
            active_admin_application.stylesheets.each do |style|
              text_node(stylesheet_link_tag(style.path, style.options).html_safe)
            end

            active_admin_application.javascripts.each do |path|
              script :src => javascript_path(path), :type => "text/javascript"
            end
            text_node csrf_meta_tag
          end
        end
```